# Interrupting in the middle of Shmona esrei

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, jewish-books, hefsek-interruption

Am I allowed to interrupt in the middle of Shmona esrei in order to pick up a Siddur (or any other holy book) that has fallen to the floor? Same question, if I have to make some steps in order to pick up a Siddur?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Mishna Berurah ([OC 96 sk 7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=252)) rules that if leaving the book on the floor will disturb your kavana (concentration), then you may pick it up in between the different blessings of shmoneh esrei. The Mishna Berura is not explicit about walking, though it does sound like he would permit it.

The [Be'er Moshe 3:13:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=888&st=&pgnum=25) explicitly permits walking to pick it up if it is bugging you.

Comment: The Sede Hemed (Michtav LeHizkiyahu #9) while talking about a case if one is allowed to be Mafsik in order to inform the Minyan to start the Hazara without him, seems to rule that it is better to walk between Berachot than to do some sort of other action (I need to see the Teshuva again BN BH).