# picking something up during shmoneh esrei

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interrupting in the middle of Shmona esrei](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13995/interrupting-in-the-middle-of-shmona-esrei)

If (chalilah) a mitzvah item such as a siddur, mezzuzah, tefillin or sefer torah falls on the floor during shmoneh esrei should a person pause and pick it up or wait until he has finished shmoneh esrei?

Comment: not sure why this was closed the other question only asked about a siddur, i can remove that part of the question but i think this question is broader in general and the answer to that question doesn't necessarily apply

Comment: Doesn't it say "or any other holy book"?

Comment: @DoubleAA i would assume mezuzah, tefillin or torah scroll are different category but your call

Comment: In my opinion, they are included in the question. They might have a different answer than siddurim, I don't know. But if you are just looking for better answers to that question then I think the correct solution is to offer a [bounty](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty). But I'm not the final say on all of this. I have posted on chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6915475#6915475) for others to come and voice their opinions if they differ.